# Object.definePropery on Array.prototype.push doesnt work

Tags: javascript, defineproperty

I want to unable the overriding option on `Array.prototype.push` on my web application.

I have tried to do so with `Object.defineProperties(Array.prototype, "push", {writable: false});`

But got an `Uncaught TypeError: Property description must be an object: p`

What did I do wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really not a good idea to do that with the prototype of a native object, this have some strong performance implications as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)

Now that you've been warned, if you want to go ahead, just use:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "push", {writable: false});
```

A better solution without the performance cost is to set writable to false specifically to the array object(s) you want to "protect".